# Mouse events listener in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, events, typescript, event-handling

Welcome everybody,
I'm struggling to change simple event listener with catching the DOM element to something more proper and correct.

**Here's plunker with my simple app:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/5x76J6i0rm5mmDRDO9QP?p=preview

If anybody would give me some hints how to change it into something better, use some other way to achieve it I would be really grateful.

I can't use DOM event listener due to server rendering. I've heard something about event emitters, but I'm not sure that I should use it in this case.

**Edit**: I don't want to use DOM listeners because sometimes it just turns off or when I upload a lot of data or click the element too many times, the listener just goes to 'sleep'. Another thing is that DOM listeners are not suggested to use in Angular2.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's fine if you need to dynamically add the event listener. The code should be moved to `ngAfterViewInit()`. The view is not fully built in `ngOnInit()` yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This listener would be fine, but somehow when I upload big data or I use this event too many times, it just starts to not respond... the listener basically turns off. This is one reason why I want to stop using it, the other reason is that it's not suggested by angular team to use DOM listeners. Would you like to help me with it? Would you like to make a full answer?

Comment: No idea what I would write into the answer. Not using DOM listeners is a great suggestion from the Angular team of course, but only if you use Angular2 only without any non-Angular libraries ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I understand. But do you have any solutions on my problem, that the listener is turning off after x time or after x actions on it? Should I reload the listeners every, let's say, 30 seconds? I know that it's stupid, but maybe would work.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I also don't see why they would stop fireing. The only think I can imagine, that Plotly re-renders the view and the element where you added the event listeners doesn't exist anymore. But I have no knowledge about Plotly

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This example in plunker is minified to show the basics of my problem. In the real, I'm using this charts to present big amounts of data, like 400k of points on one chart. It takes some time to load all the data. And another thing - there's a feature in my charts that you can click and drag the chart. That's why I need listeners, when the user drags the chart it loads more data dynamically, according to what date did he drag the chart. But if I perform this action too many times, the listeners just turns off. Maybe of the cache memory lacks?

Comment: Perhaps you should remove previously added listeners before adding the new ones.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nevermind. But would you like to tell me more about this `ngAfterViewInit()`? Should I drop the listeners there?

Comment: It seems to work in `ngOnInit()` but code that depends on the DOM, should be in `ngAfterViewInit()`. This lifecycle method is called when the view initialization is done.